# SaveInstanceOf list character?

Tags: java, android, list, onsaveinstancestate

Can someone tell me how can I save an instance of a list  in the bundle if the only method similar is putCharArray()?

Will it work or not really?

Comment: Convert the list to array ?

Comment: You might want to edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating the list that you are trying to put into the saved instance state `Bundle`.